# Circular dependency between child and parent modules

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a circular dependency between parent and child module; Even with `forwardRef` at module definitions (with or without `forwareRef` between services); it yields a circular dependency. So I have the following error:

> Potential causes:
>
> - A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
> - The module at index [3] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.
>
> Scope [AppModule -> FolderModule ->
> FolderQueueModule]

Parent module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => FolderQueueModule),
  ],
  controllers: [FolderController]
})
export class FolderModule {}
```

Child module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => FolderModule)],
  providers: [FolderQueueService],
  exports: [FolderQueueService],
})
export class FolderQueueModule {}
```

Comment: Do you have other imports in your modules? The code you posted seems fine, and the error mentions a "module at index [3]" so you might have another circular dependency or other error.

If possible, I would suggest moving the shared logic into a third module that both existing modules can use to avoid the need for circular dependencies.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I only have dependencies between children (themselves are working fine), and parent is dependent on its children modules. This is the new dependency where it fails, Child module depends on Parent. 
For tests I can do what you said to find root cause agreed, but for now I just moved this Child module up to root, so it is on the same level as Parent.
I believe it is never fine (child <=> parent) since now it worked.